# Understanding a C++ sample - printers, handles, strings

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printing

There are few question from the following code which i came across [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162959.aspx):

```
// RawDataToPrinter - sends binary data directly to a printer 
//  
// szPrinterName: NULL-terminated string specifying printer name 
// lpData:        Pointer to raw data bytes 
// dwCount        Length of lpData in bytes 
//  
// Returns: TRUE for success, FALSE for failure. 
//  
BOOL RawDataToPrinter(LPTSTR szPrinterName, LPBYTE lpData, DWORD dwCount)
{
    BOOL     bStatus = FALSE;
    HANDLE     hPrinter = NULL;
    DOC_INFO_1 DocInfo;
    DWORD      dwJob = 0L;
    DWORD      dwBytesWritten = 0L;

    // Open a handle to the printer. 
    bStatus = OpenPrinter( szPrinterName, &hPrinter, NULL );  // question 1
    if (bStatus) {
        // Fill in the structure with info about this "document." 
        DocInfo.pDocName = (LPTSTR)_T("My Document");  // question 2
        DocInfo.pOutputFile = NULL;                 // question 3
        DocInfo.pDatatype = (LPTSTR)_T("RAW");   // question 4

        // Inform the spooler the document is beginning. 
        dwJob = StartDocPrinter( hPrinter, 1, (LPBYTE)&DocInfo );  // question 5
        if (dwJob > 0) {
            // Start a page. 
            bStatus = StartPagePrinter( hPrinter );
            if (bStatus) {
                // Send the data to the printer. 
                bStatus = WritePrinter( hPrinter, lpData, dwCount, &dwBytesWritten);
                EndPagePrinter (hPrinter);
            }
            // Inform the spooler that the document is ending. 
            EndDocPrinter( hPrinter );
        }
        // Close the printer handle. 
        ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
    }
    // Check to see if correct number of bytes were written. 
    if (!bStatus || (dwBytesWritten != dwCount)) {
        bStatus = FALSE;
    } else {
        bStatus = TRUE;
    }
    return bStatus;
}
```

*Please look for the question number in comments*

**Question 1**

- when i have set `hPrinter = null` then what is meant by `&hPrinter` ?

**Question 2**

- what does `(LPTSTR)_T` denote ?  *(see T )*

**Question 3**

- What does null here denote ?

**Question 4**

- What does `RAW` mean *( what type of data it is ? )* ?

**Question 5**

- What does `1` denote here ?

Comment: Reading the MSDN documentation for the functions used will answer at least questions 3 and 5.

Comment: Are your questions specific to this method and `StartDocPrinter()`, and valid ranges of values that they accept, or concepts like casting, `&`, and datatypes like strings "RAW", and int values of 1, and null values? I'm generally confused.

Comment: @ interjay I don't understand the reason why we have to set the value = 1 . No doubt they say you have to set = 1

Comment: @Suhail: send it something other than 1, see what happens, and report back.

Comment: Like @interjay said, reading MSDN documentation will answer every question. Downvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `&hPrinter` is the address of the `hPrinter` variable. You need to pass it so the `OpenPrinter` function can write in it the actual handle to the printer.
2. `_T` takes your character string and converts it to the proper ANSI (8bits/character) or Unicode (16bits/character) representation based on your compilation settings. Basically it's a macro that either expands to nothing (ANSI) or `L` (Unicode) plus the actual string.
3. Here where, in the code? `NULL` is a macro that expands to (basically) `0`. It's used to provide a decent default value.
4. Raw data is exactly what it sounds, raw data. It's not structured in any way, it's just a soup of bytes you pass to a (usually) device.
5. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145115(v=vs.85).aspx:

   > The version of the structure to which pDocInfo points. This value must be 1.

Answer (score 6):

1. `&hPrinter` is the address of the memory space that the symbol `hPrinter` occupies. For instance, if the value of `hPrinter` were stored at the address 0x1000 (unlikely!), then the four (or eight, or more; HANDLE is defined as PVOID, so it'll vary between architectures) bytes starting at 0x1000 will contain the value 0 (NULL). In other words, while the *value* of `hPrinter` might be NULL, it still has an *address* and it still occupies *memory space*.

   **Edit**: My answer is probably not what you were after. The second parameter to `OpenPrinter` (to which you pass the address of `hPrinter`) is actually an output parameter, not an input parameter. It's a common work-around for the fact that C is limited to one return value, and most Win32 API functions return a status value. It receives a handle to the printer once the `OpenPrinter` function has finished successfully.
2. The _T() macro determines whether your project is configured to use Unicode or not, and interprets the string literal accordingly; see [MSDN's explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).
3. pOutputFile is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as:

   > Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the name of an output file. To print to a printer, set this to NULL.

   In other words: when printing to a printer rather than a file, set this to NULL. NULL    typically denotes "no value" in the context of pointer types.
4. Was better answered by others.
5. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145115%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more info, but basically:

   > The version of the structure to which pDocInfo points. This value must be 1.

   ... So I wouldn't worry too much about it if I were you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> when i have set hPrinter = null then what is meant by &hPrinter ?

When you pass &hPrinter it means you are passing the address of the handle to the api, so that the api will allocate a handle and put it inside hPrinter .

> what does (LPTSTR)_T denote ? (see T )

_T() is a macro which In a Unicode build, they puts the L before the string literal to make it wide, and in non-Unicode, does nothing.

Answer (score -2):

hPrinter is a reference parameter, which means a function can change the actual parameter involved in the function call. It is of course (behind the curtains) implemented as a pointer, so

```
    int j;
    int &i = j
    // realy is:
    int *i = &j;
```

taking the address by putting & infront of &i evaluates to the value of the 'behind the curtain' pointer.

_T("hello world") is a compiler defined macro that may return "hello world" in wide character format, in case of a unicode build. Or in case of an ANSI build: "hello world" in char's.

To answer the rest of your questions, consult the documentation, or wait for another someone to answer your questions.

Comment: The Win32 API is C-based, and thus does not allow for reference parameters, as they are specific to C++. The & is the good old C address-of operator. If you look at the declaration of OpenPrinter, you'll see that the lphPrinter parameter is declared as LPHANDLE, which expands to a HANDLE pointer.

Comment: ANSI C also supports reference types, but I'm not shure if windows api uses them. Anyway, thanks for the comment.